# AFNetworking and auto-suggest

Tags: autosuggest, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking for my iOs app.
I need to implement a search-suggest like in many other apps or search bars on  websites.
So basically launch GET requests but cancelling old ones as users tap new chars.
How can I do that? I have an AFHTTPClient subclass and I'am using getPath.
The best would be to have this requests be cancellable and "prioritized" to any other HTTP request on my singleton AFHTTPClient subclass.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this method in your AFHTTPClient

```
- (void)cancelHTTPOperationsWithMethod:(NSString *)method andURL:(NSURL *)url
```

Sample if you've a singleton on a AFHTTPClient subclasse:

```
[[MHHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] cancelHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" andURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/autocomplete.json?search=tes"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best HTTPClient in AFNetworking is used when you are trying to create an application based on a specific service, that will make requests to different paths on the same host.

For stuff like that, I would use the plain AFHTTPRequestOperation, that is cancelable. I would make a wrapper class with an AFHTTPRequestOperation inside. Then, on each user press, I would call 'cancel' on the http request (and my wrapper), and then create a new one in the same place, and make the new request. That's the way I have already implemented it in my apps, and it works fine.

Be careful though. AFNetworking is heavily NSOperation block based, and when calling cancel, you must make sure that the NSOperation's completion block will not get called (or at least, will return immediately after it gets called). Even if you cancel the operation, there's a chance that the completion block will still be called, thus creating memory leaks and hard to track bugs. Your best bet is to create a completion block and check if the operation is cancelled before proceeding.